# Add flags in bat file to open netbeans without console

Tags: batch-file, cmd, netbeans-8, flags

I want to open netbeans using cmd in win10, Added `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin` to PATH and also created a `netbeans.bat` file as :

`@START C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin\netbeans.exe /console suppress "%1"`

It is opening netbeans along with it's console. If i close this console, netbeans also closed automatically

I just want to hide console using flag `--console suppress` but i don't know how to add it in .bat file

Thank You

Comment: I would assume from what you've posted that you have not used the correct syntax for your `start` command. `@Start "" "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin\netbeans.exe" --console suppress "%~1"`, seems more like it.

Comment: @Compo Yeah, Mine is wrong method to apply flags in batch file. As per mine and yours batch file, I need to enter ```netbeans --console suppress filename``` in cmd. I want to reduce it to ```netbeans filename```

Comment: In order to not use the full path and extension for `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin\netbeans.exe`, i.e. `netbeans`, you'd need to either run it with `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin` as the current directory, _(or add `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin` to the end of your `%PATH%` System environment variable)_, and ensure that your `%PATHEXT%` System environment variable, includes `.EXE;`. In addition to that, if you don't want to suppress the console, don't add the `--console suppress` parameter!

Comment: @Compo I added ```bin``` path to  **environment**, I want to suppress console but ```--console suppress``` is not working in batch file. I have created batch file as shown in question and also tried yours not working.. I am glad you are helping thanks

Comment: @Compo In simple, I am opening netbeans using command ```start netbeans --console suppress filename```, but I want it in short form like ```netbeans filename```. Any other way to make it possible?

Comment: @Compo Idk what i tried on that day, `@Start "" "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin\netbeans.exe" --console suppress "%~1"` is working fine... thanks

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer, for you Shashank Gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume from what you've posted that you have not used the correct syntax for your `start` command.

This would seem more like it to me:

```batch-file
 @Start "" "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin\netbeans.exe" --console suppress "%~1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add  --console suppress "%~1" at the end of your netbeans command.